# Swift: How to fill view with a SK Sprite Node?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, sprite

I am trying to learn Swift by creating my own game (app), but I am having a problem.

I have a SKSpriteNode which I use as the background for the game. It's an image I've made. My problem is that my background won't fill the view so I get these grey bars outside of the Node.

What is wrong in my code?

```
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    Hintergrund = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PenaltyLocker_BG1")
    Hintergrund.size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    Hintergrund.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    Hintergrund.zPosition = 1
    Hintergrund.name = "Hintergrund"
    addChild(Hintergrund)
```

Now when I start the simulator for iPhone it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/532Hj.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Change to use the size of the SKScene.

`self.scene.size.width` / `self.scene.size.height`

```
Hintergrund.size = CGSize(width: self.scene.size.width, height: self.scene.size.height)
Hintergrund.position = CGPoint(x: self.scene.size.width/2, y: self.scene.size.height/2)
```

You can also check [this tutorial](http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-setting-up-correct-scene-dimensions) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that, but then my Background is totally stretched and that doesn't look good. Images: http://imgur.com/a/KgbQj .. Oh and i had to add "!" after scene so that it looks like "self.scene!.size.width" and "self.scene!.size.height", otherwise i get the error message "Value of optional type SKScene? not unwrapped"

Comment: All the scene or just the ball are stretched?

Comment: Just the Background (the Hintergrund node). The other nodes still look good.